# Is this set open in the product topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and equipp $X\times Y$ with the product topology. Assume $U\subset X$ is open and for every $p\in U$ we have an open subset $V_p\subset Y$ of $Y$.

Is the set

$\bigcup_{p\in U}\left(\{p\}\times V_p\right)\subset X\times Y$

open in $X\times Y$?

If not, does it hold for more specific choices, e.g. $Y$ is a metric space and $V_p=B_\varepsilon(p)$ is the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $p$ where $\varepsilon$ doesn't depend on $p$.

**EDIT :**

Replies to some of the comments -

Brandon: Thank you for your answer :-). In fact, it is not a homework problem (thats why I also added the additional question in the case of metric spaces). I tried to work with the definiton of product topology (i.e. products of open sets of $X$ and $Y$ form a basis) but couldn't come up with something useful. Then I tried to find a continuous map that has the above set as the preimage of an open set, but that attempt also flailed. Maybe it's rather simple and I'm just stuck, or the set isn't open.

Rise: Yes, thanks for noticing, one should also have $X=Y$.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math.Stackexchange. This looks like a homework problem, so please talk about what you know and why you are stuck so people can help you in a better way.

Comment: @ilod In your last line, the example you give is incorrect. $p\in U\subseteq X$. So saying $V_p=B_\epsilon(p)$ doesn't make sense. $p$ is NOT in $Y$ here.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProductTopology.html The topology on the Cartesian product $X×Y$ of two topological spaces whose open sets are the unions of subsets $A×B$, where  $A$ and $B$ are open subsets of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U = (-1,1)$, $V_x = (-1,1)$ for $x = 0$ and $V_x = (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ otherwise. There is obviously no $\varepsilon$-Ball around $(0, \frac{3}{4})$.